# AS3 OOP Principles - How far is enough

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flash-cs4, abstraction

HI Folks

Imagine you have a MC used as a container for several other MC's used as buttons.

Now, should I use the class of the container to listen for and to dispatch events.

Or

Should I create a seperate class for each MC inside of the container to listen for and to dispatch events.

In summary: One class for all, or several smaller classes dedicated to their respective MC.

How far should one go with abstraction?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually more efficient to register event listeners with a parent container than with each of its descendants. In this case, register the event listeners with the parent MovieClip. To quote Colin Moock in *Essential ActionScript 3.0*:

> "If you're waiting for a room in a fully booked hotel, it's easier to ask the hotel manager to tell you when a vacancy opens up than it is to ask every guest in the hotel to tell you when they leave."